# Invalid Redirect: You are using a sensitive scope. URI must use https:// as the scheme

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spring-security, google-oauth, google-authentication

when I log into my app, I get a message

> If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details
> comply with Google policies. redirect_uri:
> http://XXXXXX/login/oauth2/code/google

I tried to add this to the Authorized redirect URIs in my google cloud
but I get an error

> Invalid Redirect: You are using a sensitive scope. URI must use
> https:// as the scheme

[image]

also if I add a url with

> https://

then I still get a message when I log into the app

> If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details
> comply with Google policies. redirect_uri:
> http://XXXXXXX/login/oauth2/code/google

my technology stack:
java
spring
vaadin

properties file:

```
server.port=${PORT:8080}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=xxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=openid,email,profile,\
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets,\
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly,\
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file,\
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,\
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.token-uri=https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.authorization-uri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?prompt=consent&access_type=offline
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.user-info-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
```

the code that gets Credential:

```
public void initCredential(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService, Authentication authentication ) {
      OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
          "google",
          authentication.getName());
      credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
          .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET)
          .setJsonFactory(GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
     .setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())
          .build()
          .setAccessToken(authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue())
          .setRefreshToken(authorizedClient.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue());
  }
```

also Oauth2 configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.oauth2Login()
        .loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
            "/VAADIN/**",
            "/favicon.ico",
            "/robots.txt",
            "/manifest.webmanifest",
            "/sw.js",
            "/offline-page.html",
            "/frontend/**",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/notifications");
  }
}
```

as I understand it, I need to configure the use of the https protocol in the configuration, but I don't understand a little where I can configure it

it is also worth noting that the application works locally, but when deploying it to AWS and trying to login via oauth 2, I get the message

Comment: Looks like you did not change your own app's configuration, to actually use an HTTPS URL for `redirect_uri`.

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the message `You are using a sensitive scope. URI must use https:// as the scheme`

Just configuring it in Google cloud console has no effect on how your application runs. It just says that this redirect uri will be supported.

Your app when it is run is still running with http and not as https. I am going to assume that you are still in development and running this locally and you have not configured our app yet to run https.

Fix your ide.

Comment: thank you for your interest in my question. I updated the question... do you mean to transfer the application to production stuts?

Comment: No i dont mean that publishing stats. that has no effect on this error message..     What are you using to run this what  language / ide / web server.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. could you take another look at the question? (I have updated)